# Can't get params from $_POST in PhpStorm 10.0.2

Tags: php, phpstorm

Can't get params from `$_POST`. I'm sure that the code is right cause they are given by a book.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Book-O-Rama Catalog Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Book-O-Rama Catalog Search</h1>

  <form action="results.php" method="post">
    Choose Search Type:<br />
    <select name="searchtype">
      <option value="author">Author
      <option value="title">Title
      <option value="isbn">ISBN
    </select>
    <br />
    Enter Search Term:<br />
    <input name="searchterm" type="text" size="40">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the `.php` script to get the params.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Book-O-Rama Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Book-O-Rama Search Results</h1>
<?php
  // create short variable names
  $searchtype=$_POST['searchtype'];
  $searchterm=trim($_POST['searchterm']);

    echo "Search type: ".$searchtype."</br>";
    echo "search term: ".$searchterm."</br>";

  if (!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
     echo 'You have not entered search details.  Please go back and try again.';
     exit;
  }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

`$searchtype` and `$searchterm` are always empty. I can'

Comment: What kind of URLs do you see/use in the browser when executing this code?

Comment: http://localhost:63342/untitled/results.php  Apparently it's post method.

Comment: You are using PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server which currently has some issues with processing POST requests/data. Better use proper Apache/nginx/IIS/etc for serving web pages.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34787827/783119

Comment: Thank you~  Figure out the problem.

Comment: "I'm sure that the code is right cause they are given by a book." - trust us experienced devs, NEVER assume that. Even the best books will often have online errata to clear up errors.

Answer (score 0):

The option tag should be closed

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Book-O-Rama Catalog Search</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Book-O-Rama Catalog Search</h1>

  <form action="results.php" method="post">
    Choose Search Type:<br />
    <select name="searchtype">
      <option value="author">Author</option>
      <option value="title">Title</option>
      <option value="isbn">ISBN</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    Enter Search Term:<br />
    <input name="searchterm" type="text" size="40">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still doesn't work after I add all the </option>... I think it's not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am using phpstorm 2017.2, and below method work for me.

1. click dropdown list on the run button left
2. click edit configurations...
3. click +
4. select php build-in web server, and config port (like 8888), and select your document root.
5. apply and ok
6. click dropdown list on the run button left
7. select the web server you config in step 4
8. click run button
9. click dropdown list on the run button left
10. click edit configurations...
11. find your php file in javascript debug, then click
12. fix url port 63342 to 8888(config in step 4)
13. apply and ok
14. click dropdown list on the run button left
15. select the php file you want run
16. click run button

end