# PhpStorm: Simple PHP form not posting

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

I've looked at several examples and have even copied solutions; no matter what I do, my HTML data within the form *will not* ***post***.

The most typical solution on SO for users that were stuck was to include the `name` attribute, but I've had that since my first attempt.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form style="color:red;" action="test.php" method="post">
    Name: <input style="color:blue;" type="text" name="formName"><br>
    E-mail: <input style="color:blue;" type="text" name="formEmail"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Below is a snapshot of what the page looks like.

[image]

Here is the code for `test.php`

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["formName"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["formEmail"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is a picture of data I've filled in.

[image]

And the resulting page when I click **submit**.

[image]

It's been years since I've used PHP; I don't remember it being this complicated so I assume I'm either doing something wrong or something is wrong with my ini file? Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** Here are some suggestions that I've tried:

- **"Try putting `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into a test .php"**
  It worked successfully, as can be seen below.
  [image]
- **"What happens when you `var_dump($_POST)`?"**
  The only thing printed to the screen is `array(0) { }`
- **"How are you accessing this? as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `file:///file.xxx`?"**
  This actually helped narrow down the problem! As stated before, I've tried testing this in *two* ways; through PhpStorm (which deploys in a localhost environment) and through my server. I screwed up with the server method and wasn't running it through localhost; once I fixed this, the PHP script works **on the server** as expected! So now I can narrow it down to the issue being specifically with my **PhpStorm environment**, which runs the scripts in `localhost`. Please keep in mind that I've tried all suggestions with *both* the server and PhpStorm, so that means that I *did* try `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in PhpStorm and it worked as expected. Because the server method works fine, it's possible my set up, .ini, and/or php install on my machine is bad.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST)` show on the second page?

Comment: This code should work. I'm wondering if this is an environment issue?

Comment: Are the html document and test.php in the same folder?

Comment: @ceejayoz I'll try that as soon as I get to my code

Comment: Well it runs for me, so it looks like a config issue

Comment: Try putting `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` into a test `.php` file and see if it displays your PHP information. If nothing shows, your environment may be misconfigured.

Comment: @DavidWyly I originally tried it in a PhpStorm environment; first using the production ini and then later the development.ini . When neither of those worked, I tried it barebones on the apache server we have set up, no PhpStorm

Comment: @DavidWyly I already tried phpinfo() earlier and it worked as expected; it displayed my PHP info. I checked the page info but nothing seemed out of place

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Question is: ***How*** are you accessing this? as `http://localhost/file.xxx` or as `file:///file.xxx`? Two different animals here @8protons

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestion(s). I updated my question.

Comment: @DavidWyly nothing. The page goes to the my test.php page which ends up being blank. I updated my question with things I've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a well known issue with PhpStorm. You can follow this guide, [PHPstorm 10.0.3 Error 502 Bad Gateway (Due to JavaVM?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785913/phpstorm-10-0-3-error-502-bad-gateway-due-to-javavm/34787827#34787827) and will find that it fixes this problem (as it did for me). As the author states there, "*You are using PhpStorm's own built-in web server, which has some issues right now (**especially with POST requests**, e.g. WEB-17317)*.

Essentially, what I did is follow the steps on this page: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deploying+PHP+applications+with+PhpStorm

A great start is to configure your project to deploy on your server.

**Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration**

Answer (score 2):

The code works for me (and apparently, for other people). From the process of elimination, there's really only one answer to your question:

*Your environment is messed up.*

First things first, ensure that PHP is installed and running properly. Create a test `.php` file with this code:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

By visiting this page in a web browser, you *should* see a giant dump of PHP information. If you don't see anything, then PHP is not installed or configured correctly.

Comment: @8protons What happens when you echo a simple debug statement in your code? (e.g., `echo "hello world"`) Does it print it?

Comment: Yeah, it prints :/

Comment: I made some updates to my question to shows some extra troubleshooting steps I've taken.

Answer (score 1):

Please check, that test.php is in the same directory, than your first html file. If it's true, try to replace by that :

the first:

```
<form style="color:red;" method="POST" action="test.php">
    Name: <input style="color:blue;" type="text" name="formName"><br>
    E-mail: <input style="color:blue;" type="text" name="formEmail"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

test.php

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?=$_POST["formName"]?><br>
Your email address is: <?=$_POST["formEmail"]?>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
Try to add this code to your php-script's header, this will show any errors :

```
<?
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your follow up update. First, I wanted to ask if your update should start with `<?php` as opposed to `<?`? I'm not sure, sorry. I tried both anyways and all I get is a blank screen. Please read the update I made to my original question; I'm starting to think this is an environment issue on my machine or PhpStorm.

Comment: <? is short to <?php

And <?= is short to <? echo

Answer (score -3):

You forgot the ?php directive to call the interpreter.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what that means. PhpStorm was giving me an OKAY confirmation on my interpreter.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? It's hard to tell what you mean by that.

Comment: Where is this missing `<?php` I see no ships