# PhpStorm GET request to built in server does not work

Tags: php, phpstorm, http-request, get-request

I am busy reading: [PHP Web Services, 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449356567)

And I am on chapter 2 whereby I am trying to make a GET request to a PHP file that is a simple search form, the GET request code is as follows and uses PHP's stream handling with contexts to perform the request:

```
<?php

$url = "http://localhost:63344/HTTP Verbs/SimpleSearchForm.php";
$data = [
    "category" => "technology",
    "rows" => 20
];

$get_addr = $url . '?' . http_build_query($data);
$page = file_get_contents($get_addr);
echo $page;
```

The search form is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>GET Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin: 20px">
        <h1> A GET Form</h1>
        <?php if (empty($_GET)): ?>
        <form name="search" method="get" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
            Category:
            <select name="category">
                <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                <option value="sport">Sport</option>
                <option value="technology">Technology</option>
            </select>

            Rows per page: <select name="rows">
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="pure-button pure-button-primary"/>
        </form>

        <?php else: ?>
            <p>Wonderfully filtered search results</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

These are examples straight from the book and I am trying to run it using PhpStorm's built-in server. I can open the search form as expected however the built-in server just hangs when I try to make the GET request with the other script.

I was just wondering if anyone has experienced this and if so then what can I do to remedy it?

Comment: It works fine when I use nginx as opposed to PHPStorm's built-in server however still not too sure what causes PHPStorm to throw a 502...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34787827/783119