# php responds 404 while handling post request from form

Tags: php, post, http-status-code-404, phpstorm

I'm recently studying PHP using PhpStorm on Windows 10.
I tried code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="inputCheck.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" autofocus placeholder="I am..." value="" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the inputCheck.php looked like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Post Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I got the input!</h1>
    <p>name: <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I ran this in PhpStorm's built-in server. When I click the *Post* Button, I get a 404 respond. However, when I visit inputCheck.php directly, I can load the page, and if I change `$_POST` to `$_GET`, the page will respond my attached GET arguments.
p.s. I have installed PHP 5.6.22 and copied the php.ini-production file to both PHP directory and %windir%, but PhpStorm kept telling me it didn't exist during the configuration. Debug tools are not installed.

Comment: They must be in different directories, or permissions on the server are set such that you can't post to the page. You should include the URLs you use to access each of these pages in your question.

Comment: What URL do you see in a browser when it does not work? Most likely it's http://stackoverflow.com/a/34787827/783119

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37506720/2873538) answer. You might need to use other local server (apache or nginx etc) instead of PHPStorm's built-in server.

Comment: @Orions thks. It was PhpStorm's built-in server. I used IIS instead and tested the code on my remote server and both worked.