# PHP not posting (yes, name tag defined)

Tags: html, post, phpstorm, php

After reading 20+ posts (a large majority of which involve people failing to put the `name` attribute in their `input` tags), I have a stupidly simple script:

```
<form action="submit_form.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and on `submit_form.php` I have

```
<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
```

Which spits out the text below.

> Notice: Undefined index: name in
>   C:\Users...\PhpstormProjects...\submit_form.php on line 1

I've been using PHP for years though this is the first PHP project on this fresh machine so this is the first `post` type action I've tried on the new configuration. With that said, I have a feeling it has to do with my PHP configuration? What should I look for in`phpinfo()`?

As a probably very important note:

- I'm running this on PhpStorm
- I've set all the deployment settings (I use PhpStorm at work with no problem)
- After posting the form from the index page, I've had `submit_form.php` only execute `phpinfo();` and that works except...
- I get random 502's... Half of the time I see the PHP info, the other half of the time I get 502 Bad Gateway...

---

I've also tried:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])) {
 echo $_POST["name"];
}
```

Comment: You forgot to close br

Comment: @nospor Thanks, edited to fix. It was a copy and paste error

Comment: @Anant Doesn't work

Comment: Try var_dump($_POST); and show us the result

Comment: @Anant It's a php file. Im able to connect to a DB with MySQLi and everything. Literally just can't seem to post

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty `array(0) { }`

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty Even if I set `value='2'` inside the input, I still get `array(0) { }`, grrr.

Comment: I think you have to install everything from scratch again as you said  `I get random 502's... Half of the time I see the PHP info, the other half of the time I get 502 Bad Gateway...`. go to cmd and run php command and check working or not?

Comment: What the URL do you see in a browser when you executing your script? It it will be like `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/...` then it means that PhpStorm's own simple built in web server is in use .. and it has some issue with POST data -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/34787827/783119

Answer (score 0):

First try

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

Because i think you're posting data to a wrong file. that's why you're not getting anything from var_dump .. please check that submit_form.php filename

if it doesn't work!

How about try something from  beginning .

First create a file name: setup.php

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then Create another file in the same directory called post.php

```
<?php 

     if(isset($_POST["name"])) {
       $name = $_POST["name"];
     }   

     echo $name;
```

?>

Hopefully my solution will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

The following link to a blog might help you resolve your problem. It does seem that your issue is php.ini configuration related.

http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/