# PhpStorm localhost gives 502 bad gateway, but interpreter is set

Tags: php, localhost, phpstorm

I have a weird problem. I just reinstalled Windows and setup PhpStorm. It keeps giving me **502: Bad Gateway** on my project. All settings are similar to my laptop running same network and working fine.

XAMPP server is OK and running on localhost, but PhpStorm's own webserver is not running. Any ideas how to fix this? I'm out of ideas.

Tried turning off and on Windows firewall. Tried rebooting. Checked Chrome for any VPNs running. No success.

[image: Interpreter]

[image: Interpreter2]

My build:

```
PhpStorm 2017.1
Build #PS-171.3780.104, built on March 21, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b13 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: Use Apache from XAMPP to serve your web pages -- PhpStorm's built-in web server has issues with serving POST requests -- `$_POST` comes empty. No fix yet ... and no movement visible... See http://stackoverflow.com/a/34787827/783119 for links and stuff

Comment: did you install php-cgi ?

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

- install xampp in another drive except for C:  run phpstorme with
- administrator

if not work 
better solution reinstall xampp( not in C: ) and PHPstorme and clear data/cache of your browser