# $_POST Method didn't work

Tags: php

Hi i have a problem with $_POST Method.

this is my code :

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
  <input type="text"name="tb"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<?php
  echo $_POST['tb'];
?>
```

and this is error message:

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated
>   and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set
>   'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the
>   php://input stream instead.  in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Cannot
>   modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0

i used PhpStorm Editor And php-7.0.3-nts-Win32-VC14-x86.
i try to change my php.ini but it's not work.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($_POST)` after you send the form?

Comment: R u using php 5.6 or higher version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot to give Space.
2. Also check variable existence.

   ```
     <form method="post" action="index.php">
     <input type="text" name="tb"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
   </form>

    <?php
    echo $tb = isset($_POST['tb']) ? $_POST['tb']  : "";
     ?>
   ```

Comment: $_get method it's working well but $_POST not working.
i can't Understand This Error message :Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @kkaka Did you tried to replace all code with my given ans? In index.php

Comment: Set always_populate_raw_post_data =-1 in your php.ini and then try

Comment: yes i did but still i receive that message :-( "always_populate_raw_post_data" it's not exist on php 7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form method="post" action="">
 <input type="text" name="tb"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

add space in `type="text"name="tb"`
and see this
[warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated)
after change `php.ini` restart webservice

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
  <input type="text" name="tb"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<?php
  echo $_POST['tb'];
?
```

add space between HTML Tag attributes

Answer (score 0):

go to settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment:

- add a local or mounted folder
- use the root folder
- under 'Mappings' complete the deployment path (i.e http://localhost/root folder
- and the web path (i.e /root folder

works fine here