# can not get the $_POST value in php ,but $_GET is ok

Tags: php, jetbrains-ide

I use PHP 5.6 and PHPstorm 10.

html code following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="hello.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="blabla">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code following .

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["blabla"];
?>
```

But if I change the method to `GET`.
It will be work. But I can not get the post value.

Then I install WAMP Server.when just use WAMP Server to access，it worked.why?why I can not use PHPStorm to get the post value.

Comment: Weird. Should be working... Try `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: When you change it to `$_GET`, do you see the data in the query string?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes That's not the solution.

Comment: I know sir, that's why it's not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: Do you have some RewriteRule in .htaccess or httpd.conf?

Comment: Check :  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST)){ 
   echo $_POST["blabla"];
}

Comment: @PhiterFernandes can not work

Comment: @RaviHirani It returns  following information.

Comment: @Threezj: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated

Comment: What kind of URLs you were using before installing and using WAMP? Most likely it was PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server (URLs like `localhost:63342:/PROJECT_NAME/...`). If so -- then ATM built-in web server has some issues with processing POST requests -- see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check "Request Type" by below way:-

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ($method == 'POST') {
    // Method is POST
    echo "post";
    $data = isset($_POST["blabla"]) ? $_POST["blabla"] : 'notset';
    echo $data;   // print data
} elseif ($method == 'GET') {
    // Method is GET
    echo "get";
} else {
    // Method unknown may be put or delete
     echo "unknown";
}
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: return this. Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
postnotset

Comment: it just a check . But i still can not get the post value

Answer (score 1):

remove `method = "post"` of the form

PHP code following .

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST["blabla"];
?>
```