# Cannot modify header information setcookie

Tags: php

I recently upgraded from php 5.3 to php 5.6

But I received an error in my code:

```
Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (index.php:1) in core.php on line 2927
```

**LINE 2927**

```
setcookie(COOKIE_TOKEN, NULL, -1);
```

COOKIE_TOKEN is:

```
define('COOKIE_TOKEN', 'name');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent**

The issue is caused by `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.deprecated.php

*There's an example at the bottom that should help to confirm it:*

```
<?php
    ini_set('always_populate_raw_post_data',-1);
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

> PHP 5.6 deprecated automatically populating the HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
>   variable and introduced a deprecation notice. If the setting is left
>   at the default value of 0 requests in the core can trigger this notice
>   although HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA isn't being used or accessed.

See also: [Warning about `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` being deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

The warning is clear.

> Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (index.php:1) in core.php on line 2927

From http://php.net/setcookie:

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the
>   HTTP headers. Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any
>   output from your script (this is a protocol restriction). This
>   requires that you place calls to this function prior to any output,
>   including  and  tags as well as any whitespace.

Move that setcookie statement before any `HTML` appears: