# Fat Free Framework on Php 5.6 using $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I'm using Fat Free Framework 3.5 on Php 5.6 and can't get rid of the error:

> Fatal error: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is
>   deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this
>   warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use
>   the php://input stream instead.

On a shared host, I don't have access to the php.ini file.

Google told me I could add this to my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag always_populate_raw_post_data -1
</IfModule>
```

but that didn't do anything.

I've changed all instances of

```
$f3->get("BODY")
```

to

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

but this doesn't seem to help either.

What gives? How do I fix this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801316/3585500) says the cause is an empty POST and to add a filler parameter.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. I'm posting JSON in the request body. Everything works alright if I change Godaddy to php v5.5 instead of 5.6.

Comment: It's not a Fat Free Framework problem. Whenever you will send a JSON AJAX request to a PHP 5.6 with php.ini settings like yours, you will get a response like that. You need to either change php.ini or send the data in AJAX using POST values. Or, if it is a production environment, you should hide all errors (which you should do anyway on prod): https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be: don't use godaddy hosting. I switched over to a Heroku php instance and everything works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

grab the latest [dev-branch](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/archive/master.zip) and try to disable the startup error checks to get rid of this error message. maybe it helps.
follow the sample here: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/pull/125