# `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` being deprecated

Tags: php, html

so i was working on a very simple post request method like this

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST"> password:<input type="password" name="password"> <input type="submit" value="submit"> <form/>
```

and when i open it on my browser and click submit it displays the following error
[image]

and before you say anything, yes i set

> always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

as seen below:
[image]

but still the error keeps on popping.......HELP please!!!

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `$_POST`?

Comment: yes, i just wanna try the post method out.... and the funny thing is when i change the method  = "GET" it actually works perfectly.

Comment: @Harun show us the php file code

Comment: @mario I googled around a bit and it seems to work for other people

Comment: @Lokesh the only code i have in my editor is the one i included in my question

Comment: Uncomment the line in php.ini file always_populate_raw_post_data = -1

Comment: I'm going to guess you've restarted your web server after making the changes. Create a new file with the contents `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and navigate to that page to verify the settings have saved. You can also make sure that you're editing the correct php.ini file.

Comment: @Harun the same issue has been discussed here!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated

Comment: @Harun And after making the changes to php.ini file restart the server

Comment: Form the manual: **This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.6.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.** Dont waste your time on it

Comment: @mario That's not correct. [It has to be -1 to disable it fully](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26261002/2370483)

Comment: As I recall, this message pops up in the error logs of certain versions of PHP whether or not you're using the variable, just like if you don't set the timezone in the ini.

Comment: @Machavity Oh. You're right. The [boolean check](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/4797f7ad16bc65bda9dca10232c8e0c62a6830ea/main/php_content_types.c) is somewhat diffuse.

Answer (score 1):

From the [link in the config file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> If set to `TRUE`, PHP will always populate the `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` containing the raw POST data. Otherwise, the variable is populated only when the MIME type of the data is unrecognised.
>
> The preferred method for accessing raw POST data is `php://input`, and `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is deprecated in PHP 5.6.0 onwards. Setting always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 will opt into the new behaviour that will be implemented in a future version of PHP, in which `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is never defined.
>
> Regardless of the setting, `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

As per the documentation setting it to -1, rather than `TRUE` uses the PHP 7.0 version which doesn't even define `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`.

Anyway, as also mentioned in the documentation, you really should just be using `file_get_contents("php://input");` to read the raw POST data.

Comment: can you show me how i can use that in my particular case???

Comment: I did: `$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: and where do i put that exactly??

Comment: @Harun - `php://input` is a direct replacement for `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. Use `file_get_contents()` to read it. See the manual entries [for $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) and [for php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input).

Comment: Also note that it hasn't just been deprecated, but it has actually been removed entirely from PHP 7.0, so if you want your code to continue working, you absolutely must switch to the newer method. The same applies to other deprecated features.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually editing the wrong php.ini file as there are a bunch of them inside the Wamp folder... though the right one is found by clicking Wamp in your toolbar ->PHP->php.ini file and set the always_populate_raw_post_data = -1, then everything will work perfectly