# Laravel 3 issues with loading Views using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-3

I have a page with multipele `<FORM>`s

eg:

```
@foreach($build['products'] as $productid)

<form id="productid_49" method="POST" action="/products/49/custom">                                                        
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="">
<input type="button" id="btn_49" value="Click">                                                        
</form>
<div id="form_output_49">
</div>

<form id="productid_23" method="POST" action="/products/23/custom">                                                        
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="">
<input type="button" id="btn_23" value="Click">                                                         
</form>
<div id="form_output_23">
</div>

<form id="productid_15" method="POST" action="/products/15/custom">                                                        
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="">
<input type="button" id="btn_15" value="Click">                                                         
</form>
<div id="form_output_15">
</div>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
so on

@endforeach
```

When the btn is clicked, Jquery is called:

```
$('input#btn_'+productid).click( function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $('#productid_'+productid);
                var post_url = form.attr('action');
                var post_data = form.serialize();
                var div=$('#form_output_'+productid).html();

                //console.log(post_url);
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: post_url,
                    cache : false, 
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $.post(post_url, function(data){
                            $('#form_output_'+productid).html(data);
                        });   
                    }
                });      
        });
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('products/(:any)/custom', array('as' => 'compare', 'uses' => 'compares@custom'));
```

Controller:

```
public function post_custom($productid)
{
      $compare = new Compare($product_id);   
      $compare->customsingelproduct($product_id);
}
```

Lib files:

```
public function customsingelproduct($product_id)
{
    $view = View::make('view.ajaxtest');
    return $view;
}
```

It works fine but I cant seem to get the partial views, so that I can load only that  and not to reload the entire page.

There is render() but it does not work.

How can I get a partial view of the same page using AJAX and basically do `$('#form_output_'+productid).html(data);` or something

I hope I clearly describes the issue, if not please ask.

need help

Working with Laravel 3.

Comment: I can not load partial view into the page using AJAX

Comment: Yes you explained in a very basic way what the problem is... but you are not explaining what is happening for you so far. You have `return Response::json($view));` so you're returning the page as JSON. So you need `dataType: "json"` in your AJAX options for one

Comment: it returns: objects: blabla when I counsol.log but does not load the view

Comment: Ah yeah of course... so don't return it as JSON. Return it as you would a regular page. Try `return View::make('view.ajaxtest');` instead in this case...

Comment: @Jonathan it gives: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Check your `laravel.log` and report the error

Comment: @Jonathan u is hiting the right spot., I will feed back u if it works nice. need to recharge my lap

Comment: @Jonathan I am getting Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated - one thing to try reading some of the comments there would be to log out your post data and see that it is being sent properly

Comment: If you resolved with my help then I'd appreciate you gave a status update so I can fill in the correct answer and we can resolve this question?

Comment: @Jonathan Well so far I have solved the issue with loading.

however, I still have few problems: The buttons do not work

Comment: If you're original question is answered with my help then I appreciate if you update what the 500 was. I assume just a syntax error otherwise. You need to ask another question if you are having other problems. We don't help on stack overflow for free. Rep is due

Comment: @Jonathan it worked fine, had few issues but solved it.

Comment: I didn't understand why you have double ajax request nested? When you have $.ajax success you have another post request to same url

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create partial view and load normally using Jquery:

```
$('#form_output_'+productid).html(data);
```