# API returning 400 Bad Request response

Tags: api, laravel, laravel-5

I have built an API and an application that uses that API.  Everything was working but now, for some reason, I get a 400 Bad Request response.  I am not sure if I changed something in the code so I wanted to double check it was correct.

So my API call is this

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$jsonData = json_encode($data);

$req = $client->request('POST', 'https://someurl.com/api/v1/createProject', [
    'body' => $jsonData,
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($jsonData),
    ]
]);

$output = $req->getBody()->getContents();
```

The API has a route set up correctly which uses post.  The function it calls is correct, and I have changed it for testing to simply return

```
return response()->json(["Success", 200]);
```

When I test the API out within Postman, I can see that Success is returned.  When I test the API within the other application I have built, I dont even see a POST request within the console, I am just displayed a Laravel error 400 Bad Request.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks

**Update**

I have changed the request to this

```
$data= json_encode($data);

$req = $client->post('https://someurl.com/api/v1/createProject', [
    'body' => $data
]);
```

If I output `$data` after it has been encoded, I get something like this

```
{
    "projectName":"New Project",
    "clientName":"Test Client",
}
```

Within the controller function of the API that is being called, I simply do

```
return response()->json(['name' => $request->input('clientName')]);
```

The 400 error has now gone, but I now get null returned to me

```
{#326 ▼
  +"name": null
}
```

Request is being injected into the function as it should be.  Should I be returning the data in a different way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use git or any other vcs? If you do you can see if you have made changes...

Comment: I havnt made any changes to this part of the code, it used to work without any issues

Comment: So as I understand all you do is you are trying to hit route that returns (testing) "Success", using first code snippet (Guzzle).

Comment: Probably the application is sending malformed JSON.

Comment: try `$request->all()` instead of `$request->input('clientName')` and report back

Comment: Returns an empty array

Answer (score 1):

Probably you did `$ composer update` and Guzzle updated.

So if you are using newest Guzzle (guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.2.2)) you do **POST** request:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$data = ['name' => 'Agent Smith'];

$response = $client->post('http://example.dev/neo', [
    'json' => $data
]);
```

You **do not** need to specify headers.

To read response you do following:

```
$json_response = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

---

My full example (in routes file <strike>**web.php**</strike> **routes.php**)

```
Route::get('smith', function () {
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $data = ['name' => 'Agent Smith']; 

    $response = $client->post('http://example.dev/neo', [
        'json' => $data,
    ]);

    $code = $response->getStatusCode();
    $result = json_decode($response->getBody());

    dd($code, $result);
});

    Route::post('neo', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        return response()->json(['name' => $request->input('name')]);
    });
```

or you could use following (shortened), but code above is "shorter"

```
$json_data = json_encode(['name' => 'Agent Smith']);

$response = $client->post('http://example.dev/neo', [
    'body' => $json_data,
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($json_data),
    ]
]);
```

> **note**: If you are running **PHP5.6**, change `always_populate_raw_post_data` to `-1` (or uncomment the line) in php.ini and restart your server. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated).

Comment: @kate_hudson see update, its working as expected, I removed pre-update full example and replaced it with new one. Read answer from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using public IP address in BASE_URL while I should have been using the private IP.  From mac you can get your IP by going into system preferences -> network.

This is with Android + Laravel (API)