# disabling always_populate_raw_post_data in php.ini does not work

Tags: php, laravel

Today when I want to send some data via **axios Vuejs** plugin, php throws this error:

```
Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
```

After googling and searching for solution I found that , I can uncomment and  change the value of `always_populate_raw_post_data` to -1 can solve the problem. But that could not solve problem and it is continued.

I used `phpinfo()` to detect real `php.ini` file and sure that I changed it properly.

I'm using **php 5.6.25** and **wamp 3.0.6** 64bit on windows 8.

Comment: Did you restart your Apache server after changing php.ini?

Comment: Yes, Of course , several times.

Comment: take a look at this page : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated

Comment: I had this problem too, in my case I mistakenly modified php.ini from wamp folder, but of course I had to edit php.ini from wamp64 folder.

Comment: I tried `phpinfo()` and used direction that it shows me. is it not right ?

Comment: Is this variable set somewhere in your code with `set_ini()`? If you search for "always_populate_raw_post_data", does anything come up?

Comment: No, I had never heard of it before. I searched for that in whole project and did not found any match.

Comment: Probably like Carl said you modified the wrong ini file. There are two: one for cli and one for Apache, so I you need to change the one for Apache.

Comment: I know that one located at `D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25` and another one is located at `D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25` named `phpForApache.ini`. I'm sure that I changed that option in both files but problem in continued.

Comment: Hooooray, after restarting windows, problem solved!!