# POST method to send form data with AJAX without JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script in js that sends the form data from one page to the server and it works well with a Jquery function but I would like to be able to do it without the use of Jquery. When I try without jQuery the form is sent but the mail arrives empty, without sender, without subject and without message. Thanks in advance.

### script con jQuery (OK)

```
$("#contact-form").on("submit", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "php/email-sender.php",
     data: {
       name: $("#contact-form #name").val(),
       email: $("#contact-form #email").val(),
       subject: $("#contact-form #subject").val(),
       message: $("#contact-form #message").val()
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
    console.log(“success”);
       } else {
          console.log(“error”);
       }
     },
     error: function() {
         console.log(“error”);
     }
   });
 });
```

### PHP script that receives the data

```
session_cache_limiter('nocache');    
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));    
header('Content-type: application/json');      

$Recipient = 'info@ejemplo.com'; // <-- Set your email here    

if($Recipient) {      

    $Name = $_POST['name'];  
    $Email = $_POST['email'];  
    $Subject = $_POST['subject'];  
    $Message = $_POST['message'];  
    if (isset($_POST['category'])) {  
        $Category = $_POST['category'];  
    }

    $Email_body = "";    
    if (isset($_POST['category'])) {  
        $Email_body .= "From: " . $Name . "\n" .  
        "Email: " . $Email . "\n" .  
        "Subject: " . $Subject . "\n" .  
        "Message: " . $Message . "\n" .  
        "Category: " . $Category . "\n";  
    } else {  
        $Email_body .= "From: " . $Name . "\n" .  
        "Email: " . $Email . "\n" .  
        "Subject: " . $Subject . "\n" .  
        "Message: " . $Message . "\n" .   
        "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());  
    }   

    $Email_headers = "";  
    $Email_headers .= 'From: ' . $Name . ' <' . $Email . '>' . "\r\n".  
    "Reply-To: " .  $Email . "\r\n";  

    $sent = mail($Recipient, $Subject, $Email_body, $Email_headers);  

    if ($sent){   
        $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'yes');  
    } else{  
        $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'no');  
    }  

    echo json_encode($emailResult);  

} else {  

    $emailResult = array ('sent'=>'no');  
    echo json_encode($emailResult);  

}
```

### Associated HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" role="form">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="Nombre" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electronico" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Asunto" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <textarea class="box-msg" rows="6" id="message" name="message">     </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="submit-button btn btn-default">
      </div>
</form>
```

### Test1 without jQuery (does not work)

```
// Submit contactForm START
const contactForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");

contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "/php/email-sender.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
  );

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      // request end.
      if (request.status == 200) {
        // success START
        console.log(request.response);
        // success END
      } else {
        // error START
        console.log("error");
        // error END
      }
    }
  };

  var formData = new FormData();
  data.append("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
  data.append("email", document.getElementById("email").value);
  data.append("subject", document.getElementById("subject").value);
  data.append("message", document.getElementById("message").value);
  request.send(formData);
});
```

### Test2 without jQuery (does not work)

```
var contactForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");

contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "/php/email-sender.php", true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;  charset=UTF-8");

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      // request end.
      if (request.status == 200) {
        // success START
        console.log(request.response);
        // success END
      } else {
        // error START
        console.log("error");
        // error END
      }
    }
  };

  var data = {
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    subject: document.getElementById("subject").value,
    message: document.getElementById("message").value
  };
  request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Comment: Does the console yield any errors?

Comment: what's wrong with using jquery ?

Comment: @niceman the script in jQuery works, but there is a tendency to not use jQuery, which is why I am trying to eliminate my dependency on jQuery. In fact, jQuery is no longer used to develop javascripts with Framework as VUE or ANGULAR although it is much more practical and I personally think it is quite efficient jQuery as its promise indicates "write me less and do more" but it is also real that convention is removing jQuery as dependency. Nothing personal, tried to follow trends.

Comment: @Script47 the console does not produce errors, the form is sent but the mail arrives empty, without sender, without subject, without message. I think the problem is in the way in which the data is packaged to be sent but I can not detect the error.

Comment: @Nelson there are some errors in your javascript and php code. please check my answer.

Comment: @RobertAnthonyS.Tribiana thank you I will review and try and comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your first javascript will return error because the data object is not defined.

Try this one

```
        const contactForm = document.getElementById("contact-form");

            contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
                
              event.preventDefault();
              
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var url = "/php/email-sender.php";
                request.open("POST", url, true);
                request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                        var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.response);
                        console.log(jsonData);
                    }
                };
                var name =  document.getElementById("name").value;
                var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
                var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
                
                
                var data = JSON.stringify({"name": name, "email": email, "subject": subject, "message": message});
     
              
                request.send(data);
     
            });  

</script>
```

Check this thread on how to receive json POST:
[Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Then Try this to your PHP file

```
<?php
// Handling data in JSON format on the server-side using PHP
header("Content-Type: application/json");
// build a PHP variable from JSON sent using POST method
$v = json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")));
echo json_encode($v);
?>
```

To access the object in your PHP file, use

```
$v->name;
$v->email;
$v->subject;
$v->message;
```

SCREENSHOT:
[image]
https://s9.postimg.cc/w1fc8266n/2018-05-03_20h37_08.gif

Comment: However now I present the following problem but the server indicates the following error message:

PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @Nelson what PHP version are you using?
I hope these links can help you:

https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/6465
and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated

Comment: Many thanks again, apparently assign -1 to the variable 'always_populate_raw_post_data' in php.ini apparent php error 5.6

Comment: No worries, if you find this helpful you can vote up =)

Comment: Missing semicolon on.... $v = json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")))

Comment: Apart from the missing simicolon, it works flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @JohnKBell . I updated my post